# Weird std::stringstream behaviour in C++

Tags: c++

This is the code:

```
std::string Query_Set::get_sql() const throw()
{
    std::stringstream out;
    int counter = 0;

    out << "WHERE " << time_name << " >= :start_time_" << counter++ << " AND " << time_name << " <= :finish_time_" << counter++ " AND something_else = :" << counter++;

    return out.str();
}
```

This code is pretty straight forward, but when I print out this String it does something weird:

```
"WHERE time >= :start_time_2 AND time <= :finish_time_1 AND something_else = :0"
```

Have I missed something simple? Why is the counter going **backwards**?

Comment: Because you are towing with undefined behaviour. You are just invoking a much more complicated version of `i = ++i + i++;`.

Comment: Because if you put strings in a stream using the operator `<<` this is parsed starting from the rightmost one.

Comment: try to write it in a different format and you'll find out:

out << ("WHERE " << (time_name << (" >= :start_time_" << (counter++ << (" AND " << (time_name << (" <= :finish_time_" << (counter++ " << (AND something_else = :" << (counter++))))))))));

Comment: @a-guest Wrong. It is `((out << stuff) << more) << stuff`.

Comment: @quantdev: Yes, it is an issue with sequence points, and the behavior is undefined. A simplified expression is this: `cout.operator<<(i++).operator<<(i++);` -- While the first call to `operator<<` is definitely sequenced before the second call to `operator<<`, the evaluation of the arguments to each of those calls (the i++, in both cases) are unsequenced relative to each other, resulting in UB.

Comment: Thanks everyone, it confused the heck out of me when I saw the output.

Answer (score 0):

The order of evaluation of arguments to an expression is undefined in C++. The second `counter++` may happen before the first. I've even seen different behaviour for such expressions in Clang and GCC.

Comment: The order is *unspecified* and if thedifferent arguments include writes to the same variable then it is *undefined behaviour*.